# Making jQRangeSlider select point?

Tags: jquery

I found jQRangeSlider a great tool to choose date. However, I cannot find an option to use it choose only a day rather than a range. Is it possible to do so? Or is there any alternative? Thanks!

Comment: how about a simple calendar?

Comment: @Banana I do really need a slider.